Preventing Framer Motion animations from getting interrupted when visibility changes in React
Issue Description:
I'm currently using React with Framer Motion library to animate elements based on their visibility in the viewport. I've implemented animations using useInView and useAnimate, and they work well when the visibility changes. However, I've noticed that if the visibility changes while a previous animation is still in progress, it can disrupt the desired animation flow.
Reproduction Steps:
Set up a component with animations triggered by visibility using useInView and useAnimate.
Scroll the component in and out of view rapidly, especially when animations are still ongoing.
Expected Behavior:
The animations should smoothly transition regardless of changes in visibility, without being interrupted by new visibility events.
Actual Behavior:
Animations sometimes get interrupted when visibility changes occur while a previous animation is still in progress. This can lead to unexpected behavior and disrupt the desired animation flow.
Attempts to Solve:
I've tried implementing a queue system to manage animations, but haven't been successful so far. I suspect I may be missing something in my implementation or there might be a better approach to handle animation interruptions.
Code Sample
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { motion, useInView, useAnimate } from "framer-motion";
import SVG from 'react-inlinesvg';

const Section3 = () => {
    const sectionRef = useRef(null)
    const isInView = useInView(sectionRef, {
        margin: "0px 0px -300px 0px"
    })
    const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();

    const startAnimation = async () => {
        await animate("button", { scale: 1, backgroundColor: "#2e4e71", borderWidth: "24px" });
        await animate("button", { borderWidth: "0px" });
        await animate("button", { backgroundColor: "rgb(66 66 69/70%)" });
        await animate("#iconSpan", { scale: 1 });
        await animate("#contentSpan", {
            opacity: 1,
            width: "auto",
            marginInlineStart: "8px",
            marginInlineEnd: "12px",
        });
    }

    const reverseAnimation = async () => {
        await animate("#contentSpan", {
            opacity: 0,
            width: 0,
            marginInlineStart: "0px",
            marginInlineEnd: "0px",
        });
        await animate("#iconSpan", { scale: 0 });
        await animate("button", { scale: 0 });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isInView) {
            startAnimation()
        } else {
            reverseAnimation()
        }
    }, [isInView])

    return (
        <section ref={sectionRef} className="bg-black flex flex-col justify-end relative text-white text-center  h-[500px]">
            <div className="sticky bottom-0 flex justify-center items-center h-40" ref={scope}>
                <motion.button initial={{ scale: 0, borderWidth: "0px" }}
                    className="backdrop-effect rounded-full  border-[#016dda]">
                    <div className="flex items-center p-2.5 min-h-[56px] min-w-[56px]">
                        <motion.span id="contentSpan" initial={{
                            opacity: 0,
                            width: 0,
                            marginInlineStart: "0px",
                            marginInlineEnd: "0px",
                        }} className="text-white overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap font-semibold w-0 opacity-0">
                            자세한 방법 모두 알아보기
                        </motion.span>
                        <motion.span id="iconSpan" initial={{ scale: 0 }} className=" bg-[#0071e3] rounded-full flex justify-center items-center text-white">
                            <SVG src="/assets/icons/more.svg" />
                        </motion.span>
                    </div>
                </motion.button>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Section3;


